# Simple Probability Question - Using the same method on two questions and given wrong result

Tags: probability, combinations

For one question, it says asks what the probability that out of $5$ chickens purchased, the probability that at least $3$ are free range given that the probability of getting a free range chicken is $0.4$ and the probability of getting a big chicken is $0.6$. So to find the answer to this, I would just take:

$$P(3~\text{are free range})+P(4~\text{are free range})+P(5~\text{are free range})\\ = (5C3)(0.4)^3(0.6)^2+(5C4)(0.4)^4(0.6)^1+(5C5)(0.4)^5$$

This would get me the correct answer.

But for another question, which says that a jury of $12$ members are to be selected out of $8$ men and $8$ women. What is the probability that if the choice is made randomly, the majority of the jury will be men ($7$ or $8$ men on the jury). How come when I use the same method:
$$P(7~\text{men}) + P(8~\text{men})\\
= (8C7~\text{men})(8C5~\text{women})(0.5)^{12}+(8C8~\text{men})(8C4~\text{women})(0.5)^{12}$$
and this gives me the wrong answer.

I know that for this question, you're supposed to take:

(Total possibilities of 7 men + Total possibilities of 8 men) / total amount of jury selections possible (16C12) so:
$$= \frac{(8C7~\text{men})(8C5~\text{women})+(8C8~\text{men})(8C4~\text{ women})}{16C12}$$

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The difference between the two questions is that in the first question, there are "*a large number of chickens*" to choose from, and so the probabilities are (*assumed to be*) independent.  In the second question, the number of people available to choose from is small enough to matter, and once one person is selected, the probabilities for the second person will have changed depending on what was chosen for the first.  The probabilities are *not* independent in the second problem.

Comment: so in the first question, since theres a large amount to choose from, even if I take 1 chicken out, the chances of taking another chicken out arent affected whereas in the second question, if i take 1 man out, then the probabilities of choosing a man or a woman is not (0.5) anymore? is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you see the question as counting the number of juries with a male majority divided by the total number of juries, then your problem is with the denominator, the total number of ways of choosing a jury of twelve from sixteen people

It is not $2^{12}=4096$. This is the total number of subsets of a set with $12$ elements, with the subsets ranging from $0$ elements through to $12$ elements. You in fact want the number of subsets with $12$ elements of a set with $16$ elements

The direct approach would be to say it is ${16 \choose 12} = 1820$

The indirect approach, consistent with your calculation of the numerator of ${8 \choose 7}{8 \choose 5} + {8 \choose 8}{8 \choose 4}$, would be to say it is ${8 \choose 4}{8 \choose 8} + {8 \choose 6}{8 \choose 7} + {8 \choose 6}{8 \choose 6} + {8 \choose 7}{8 \choose 5} + {8 \choose 8}{8 \choose 4} = 1820$, the same correct value